# Combine 2 or more JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

My current JSON value is like this:

```
{"vegetable_names":["vegetables 1","vegetables 2","vegetables 3"]}{"grade":["XXL","A","B","S"]}{"packages":["Carton Boxes","Baskets"]}
```

But I would like to want the output to be like this:

```
{"vegetable_names":["vegetables 1","vegetables 2","vegetables 3"],"grade":["XXL","A","B","S"],"packages":["Carton Boxes","Baskets"]}
```

Comment: `echo '{"vegetable_names":["vegetables 1","vegetables 2","vegetables 3"],"grade":["XXL","A","B","S"],"packages":["Carton Boxes","Baskets"]}';` Seriously though, we're going to need to see your code to provide any useful help.

Comment: If you won't clarify how the data was produced, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is just a text representation of some data structure. Restore the data structure from the JSON strings, use PHP to modify it (or create a new data structure if it's more appropriate), encode the updated/new data structure to `JSON` again.

It seems the "JSON" you posted as input is not a `JSON` at all. It is the concatenation of three `JSON` strings. It doesn't work this way!

```
// Input JSON strings
$json1 = '{"vegetable_names":["vegetables 1","vegetables 2","vegetables 3"]}';
$json2 = '{"grade":["XXL","A","B","S"]}';
$json3 = '{"packages":["Carton Boxes","Baskets"]}';

// Restore the data structures as arrays
$data1 = json_decode($json1, TRUE);
$data2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);
$data3 = json_decode($json3, TRUE);

// Combine them; it seems all you need is a simple merging
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3);

// Encode the combined arrays as JSON again
$output = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the Json like you described. If not I suggest you follow Paul Crovella's solution in making it right from the start.

So presumed that is no option for you, how about decoding the Json to an object or array merging those two or more and then encode them again as Json. 
Ugly , but if the Json is created by a source independent from you, you can do it like that.